# Why is my spritesheet being loaded multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-sprites

I have a spritesheet driving the appearance of a group of buttons, which change in response to various mouse operations. However, I can see a flicker when switching between sprites, and looking at the network panel in chrome or firebug confirms that the spritesheet is being reloaded every time a sprite is changed, which defeats the point of using a spritesheet.

The jquery code to handle swapping out sprites is this:

```
$(".btn").mouseover(function () {
    var imgId = $(this).prop("id");
    if (imgList[imgId]) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass(imgList[imgId]["inactive"])) {
            $(this).removeClass(imgList[imgId]["all"]).addClass(imgList[imgId]["mouseOver"]);
        }
    }
});

$(".btn").mousedown(function () {
    var imgId = $(this).prop("id");
    if (imgList[imgId]) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass(imgList[imgId]["inactive"])) {
            $(this).removeClass(imgList[imgId]["all"]).addClass(imgList[imgId]["mouseDown"]);
        }
    }
});

$(".btn").mouseout(function () {
    var imgId = $(this).prop("id");
    if (imgList[imgId]) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass(imgList[imgId]["inactive"])) {
            $(this).removeClass(imgList[imgId]["all"]).addClass(imgList[imgId]["default"]);
        }
    }
});
```

Where imgList is a list of class names used to apply the sprites, with all being the full list of classes. Here's a sample:

```
imgList["navToggleNavigation"] = [];
imgList["navToggleNavigation"]["default"] = "NavShowHide-Button-normal";
imgList["navToggleNavigation"]["mouseOver"] = "NavShowHide-Button-mouseOver";
imgList["navToggleNavigation"]["mouseDown"] = "NavShowHide-Button-mouseDown";
imgList["navToggleNavigation"]["inactive"] = "NavShowHide-Button-inactive";
imgList["navToggleNavigation"]["select"] = "NavShowHide-Button-select";
imgList["navToggleNavigation"]["all"] = "NavShowHide-Button-normal NavShowHide-Button-mouseOver NavShowHide-Button-mouseDown NavShowHide-Button-inactive NavShowHide-Button-select";
```

The CSS code for each of these classes references an image in the sheet:

```
.NavShowHide-Button-inactive{background-image:url('../Images/navigation-spritesheet.png') ; background-position:-704px 0px ; height: 44px; width: 44px; display: inline-block;}
.NavShowHide-Button-mouseDown{background-image:url('../Images/navigation-spritesheet.png') ; background-position:-748px 0px ; height: 44px; width: 44px; display: inline-block;}
.NavShowHide-Button-mouseOver{background-image:url('../Images/navigation-spritesheet.png') ; background-position:-792px 0px ; height: 44px; width: 44px; display: inline-block;}
.NavShowHide-Button-normal{background-image:url('../Images/navigation-spritesheet.png') ; background-position:-836px 0px ; height: 44px; width: 44px; display: inline-block;}
.NavShowHide-normal{background-image:url('../Images/navigation-spritesheet.png') ; background-position:-880px 0px ; height: 44px; width: 44px; display: inline-block;}
```

Is there anything in this code that would cause the spritesheet to be reloaded when it runs? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring a `background-image` on every class, you should have a single classname (like `.NavShowHide`) that has the `background-image` and then use the more specific classes to define the `background-position` only:

```
.NavShowHide {
    background-image:url('../Images/navigation-spritesheet.png'); 
    height: 44px; 
    width: 44px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
.NavShowHide-Button-inactive{background-position:-704px 0px;}
.NavShowHide-Button-mouseDown{background-position:-748px 0px;}
.NavShowHide-Button-mouseOver{background-position:-792px 0px;}
.NavShowHide-Button-normal{background-position:-836px 0px;}
.NavShowHide-normal{background-position:-880px 0px;}
```

Then give the element a combination of both classes, i.e.:

```
<div class="NavShowHide NavShowHide-Button-normal">My Button</div>
```